# DataGridView with ICustomTypeDescriptor looks empty on Mono

Tags: c#, datagridview, mono

As part of a larger application I have a DataGridView that shows a list of objects implementing ICustomTypeDescriptor, wrapping the actual records. When running the application on Mono (or Wine) the cells of the DataGridView all looks empty. The same application works fine on Windows.

I prepared a [small application](https://gist.github.com/hackedd/d088cd5a32d21964776e) that exhibits the same behaviour. It contains two DataGridViews, the first one shows a list of persons, the second one shows the same list, but wrapped in an object implementing ICustomTypeDescriptor. The ICustomTypeDescriptor is a dummy, basically forwarding all calls to TypeDescriptor.

The application running on Mono ([on Wine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vw3V.png)):

[image: The application on Mono]

The application running on Windows:

[image: The application on Windows 7]

How do I find out why this is? Or better yet, how do I fix it?